# Convert a string to preexisting variable names

Tags: python

How do I convert a string to the variable name in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)?

For example, if the program contains a object named `self.post` that contains a variable named, I want to do something like:

```
somefunction("self.post.id") = |Value of self.post.id|
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As referenced in Stack Overflow question *[Inplace substitution from ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295028/)*, you're looking for `eval()`:

```
print eval('self.post.id') # Prints the value of self.post.id
```

Comment: Why not use setattr() ?

Answer (score 55):

Note: do **not** use eval in any case where you are getting the name to look up from user entered input. For example, if this comes from a web page, there is nothing preventing anyone from entering:

```
__import__("os").system("Some nasty command like rm -rf /*")
```

as the argument. Better is to limit to well-defined lookup locations such as a dictionary or instance using [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr). For example, to find the "post" value on self, use:

```
varname = "post"
value = getattr(self, varname)  # Gets self.post
```

Similarly to set it, use setattr():

```
value = setattr(self, varname, new_value)
```

To handle [fully qualified names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name), like "post.id", you could use something like the below functions in place of getattr() / [setattr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
def getattr_qualified(obj, name):
    for attr in name.split("."):
        obj = getattr(obj, attr)
    return obj

def setattr_qualified(obj, name, value):
    parts = name.split(".")
    for attr in parts[:-1]:
        obj = getattr(obj, attr)
    setattr(obj, parts[-1], value)
```

Comment: What if there is no 'self'? I.e. you're in global scope. Then I guess vars()['name'] has to be used, or is there a getattr fallback somehow?

Answer (score 23):

Also, there is the **[globals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals)** function in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) which returns a dictionary with all the defined variables. You could also use something like this:

```
print globals()["myvar"]
```

Answer (score 17):

You could do something like what Geo recommended, or go with:

```
>>> wine = 'pinot_noir'
>>> vars()[wine] = 'yum'
>>> pinot_noir
'yum'
```

<strike>Note: vars() and globals() are the same, I'm just used to using vars()</strike>
I'm surprised nobody called me out on this! Anyway, it's `vars()` and *`locals()`* that are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var="variable name"
def returnvar(string):
    exec(f"""global rtn
rtn={string}""")
    return rtn
```

var will be your string and run returnvar(var) will to return variable

Comment: Have you attempted this answer on your own? Is there anything `returnvar` does that `eval` does not do?

Comment: I found the mistake and I have fixed it