# Append series of items to list with similar names in Python

Tags: python, list, append

I have a series of lists with two items in each of them called box1, box2, box3, etc. and am trying to append to a master list to access later. Below is what I thought would work, but it is not. I think it may be something with the string in the `append` method adding to `i`, but I am not sure.

This is obviously only adding the string box + `i`, but I need to figure out a way to loop through and add all similarly named items to this list. What is the best way to accomplish this goal?

```
box1 = [1,2]
box2 = [3,4]
boxes = []

##Adding strings. I need to add box items instead.
for i in range(11):
    boxes.append("box" + str(i))
```

I want to see this:

```
boxes = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

FYI: I cannot use imported libraries for this due to the software I am limited to using.

Comment: You shouldn’t have local variables `box1` to `box10` to begin with… Put it in a dictionary, or just directly into `boxes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(11):
    box = locals().get('box' + str(i))
    if box is not None:
        boxes.append(box)
```

Note that it would be better in my opinion to refactor your code so that instead of defining the variables `box1`, `box2`, etc. you would create a dictionary and then do something like `box_dict['box1'] = [1, 2]`.  This would allow you to easily lookup these lists later by the name.

Comment: At module level `locals()` is `globals()`, so it would work either way.

Comment: thanks, i think i will explore the dictionary options per this comment.  thought i was keeping it simple with a list in a list.  I really dont need to resuse the code a lot, but i think enough to justify a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()`, in your case it will be:

```
boxes = [eval('box%d' %i) for i in range(1,3)]
```

If you have a list with the box names you want to add to boxes, you can simply do:

```
boxes = [eval(boxname) for boxname in boxnames]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
box1 = [1,2]
box2 = [3,4]
boxes = []
##adding strings, need to add box items instead
for i in range(1,3):
    boxes.append(locals()["box" + str(i)])
```

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - I agree, it's bad style, but that's not really the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a poor way to code, but you can do it like this

```
import itertools

boxes=[]
for i in itertools.count(1):
    name='box{}'.format(i)
    if name not in locals():
       break
    boxes.append(locals()[name])
```

For the no-libraries version:

```
boxes=[]
i=1
while True:
    name='box{}'.format(i)
    if name not in locals():
       break
    boxes.append(locals()[name])
    i+=1
```

Comment: I think not `break` but `continue`

Comment: should be `break`, since there is a `not in` in there

Comment: i cannot use imported libraries with what i am limited to right now, thank you for the answer however, i will edit my post to include this info.

Comment: what if `box3` is absent and `box7` is present

Comment: op doesn't have that in the example, but in that case a loop over all locals is needed, which is even more expensive

Answer (score 0):

One can use the [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) function to get a dictionary of available variables:

```
box1 = [1,2]
box2 = [3,4]
boxes = []

##Adding strings. I need to add box items instead
for i in range(11):
    key = "box%d" % i
    if key in vars():
         boxes.append(vars()[key])
boxes
```

Also, you should consider to check [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).

Answer (score 0):

```
 boxDict={}
 boxes=[]
 for i in range(1,11):
      box = [i, i+1]
      boxDict[i] = box
      boxes.append(box)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to Stack Overflow question *[Convert a string to preexisting variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295058)*, but to save time, you can use `getattr(object, name)` to get a variable with a particular name out of an object.

You might have something like:

```
for i in range(11):
    boxes.append(getattr(self, "box"+i))
```