# Python: YAML dictionary of functions: how to load without converting to strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, yaml

I have a YAML config file, which contains a dictionary, like so:

```
"COLUMN_NAME": column_function
```

It maps strings to functions (which exist and are supposed to be called).

However, when I load it using `yaml`, I see that the loaded dictionary now maps strings to strings:

```
'COLUMN_NAME': 'column_function'
```

Now I cannot use it as intended - `'column_function'` doesn't point to `column_function`.

What would be a good way to load my `dict` so that it maps to my functions? After searching and reading a bit on this issue, I'm very cautious about using `eval` or something like that, since the config file is user-edited.

I think [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295058/convert-a-string-to-preexisting-variable-names) is about my issue, but I'm not sure on the best way to approach it.

- `getattr` and `setattr` are out, I think, because they operate on instantiated objects, whereas I have a simple script.
- `globals()`, `vars()` and `locals()` provide me with `dict`s of variables, and I suppose I should use `globals()`, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7969953/2143578).

Should I look up the string in them for each of key-value pairs in my config `dict`? Is this a good way:

```
for (key, val) in STRING_DICTIONARY.items():
    try: 
        STRING_DICTIONARY[key] = globals()[val]   
    except KeyError:
        print("The config file specifies a function \"" + val 
               + "\" for column \"" + key 
               + "\". No such function is defined, however. ")
```

Answer (score 2):

To lookup a name `val` and evaluate it in a generic way I would use the following:

```
def fun_call_by_name(val):
    if '.' in val:
        module_name, fun_name = val.rsplit('.', 1)
        # you should restrict which modules may be loaded here
        assert module_name.startswith('my.')
    else:
        module_name = '__main__'
        fun_name = val
    try:
        __import__(module_name)
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ConstructorError(
            "while constructing a Python object", mark,
            "cannot find module %r (%s)" % (utf8(module_name), exc), mark)
    module = sys.modules[module_name]
    fun = getattr(module, fun_name)
    return fun()
```

This is adapted from `ruamel.yaml.constructor.py:find_python_name()`, used there to create objects from string scalars. If the `val` that is handed in, contains a dot, it will assume you are looking up a function name in another module.

But I wouldn't magically interpret values from your top-level dictionary. YAML has a tagging mechanism (and for specific tags the `find_python_name()` method comes into action, to control the type of instances that are created).
If you have any control over how the YAML file looks like, use tags to selectively not create a string, as in this file `input.yaml`:

```
COLUMN_NAME: !fun column_function    # tagged
PI_VAL: !fun my.test.pi              # also tagged
ANSWER: forty-two                    # this one has no tag
```

Assuming a subdirectory `my` with a file `test.py` with contents:

```
import math
def pi():
    return math.pi
```

You can use:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def column_function():
    return 3

def fun_constructor(loader, node):
    val = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    return fun_call_by_name(val)

# add the constructor for the tag !fun
ruamel.yaml.add_constructor('!fun', fun_constructor, Loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)

with open('input.yaml') as fp:
    data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(fp)
assert data['COLUMN_NAME'] == 3
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

to get:

```
COLUMN_NAME: 3                       # tagged
PI_VAL: 3.141592653589793            # also tagged
ANSWER: forty-two                    # this one has no tag
```

If you don't care about dumping `data` as YAML with comments preserved, you can use `SafeLoader` and `safe_load()` instead of `RoundTripLoader` resp. `round_trip_loader()`.