# How to assign to a variable a variable name to get the value of the variable?

Tags: python

**How to assign to a variable a variable name to get the value of the variable?** 
This works

```
a=1
b=a
```

it outputs a if you used`print(b)` you will get 1.But if i used this,

```
 for i in range (0,a1,2):
     r=i/2
     e[r] ='c%s'%i
     print(e[r])
```

(c0, c2, c4,... has a value) 
then it will output c0, c2, c4... 
How can i make it output the value of c0,c2,c4...?
I tried changing the `''`to`" "`but it still don't work.

Comment: Use a dictionary, like `{'c0': 1, 'c2': 7, ...}`.

Comment: If I understand this correctly you are looking for eval. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295058/convert-a-string-to-preexisting-variable-names

Comment: @ConnorWilson, ...that's a dangerous (literally, in the security-bug-prone sense) path to send someone down, when responsive answers that fit with best practices are also available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `dict` to store your "variable" named variables:

```
>>> variables = {}
>>> prefix = 'c'
>>> variables[prefix + '0'] = 123
>>> variables[prefix + '0']
123
>>> variables['c0'] # is the same thing as the above
123
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
c0, c2, c4, ...
```

but use

```
c[0], c[2], c[4], ...
```

and then change your loop

```
 for i in range (0,a1,2):
     r=i/2
     e[r] ='c%s'%i
     print(e[r])
```

into

```
 for i in range (0,a1,2):
     r=i/2
     e[r] = c[i]       # Here is the difference
     print(e[r])
```

Comment: Might also cover how to initialize `c`.