# Why does my simple code not work when invoking a function using inputted values?

Tags: python

As an exercise I have been tasked with writing a function that will check if a given container contains a searched value, returning `True` if it does and `False` if it doesn't. I have created the following function:

```
setContainer = {i for i in range(1000)}
listContainer = [i for i in range(1000)]

def does_it_contain(container, value):
    if value in container:
        return True
    if value not in container:
        return False
```

which works fine when I invoke the function explicitly.

However I am trying to add some code to let the user search for a value in the container of his choice like:

```
checkValue = input("Search for: ")
checkContainer = input("Seach in container named: ")

print(does_it_contain(checkContainer, checkValue))
```

But this seems to always yield `False`, and I can't figure out why. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. When you say use `checkContainer` as your container, it is simply a string, not a container with values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the user inputs a string which can be identical to the name of your container's name, but it won't be the container object you defined in your code.

Instead you should create a mapping, e.g. a dictionary, in which you store the reference of your containers, and you can pick the right one based on the user's input:

```py
setContainer = {i for i in range(1000)}
listContainer = [i for i in range(1000)]

container_switcher = {
    "setContainer": setContainer,
    "listContainer": listContainer,
}


def does_it_contain(container, value):
    if value in container:
        return True
    if value not in container:
        return False


checkValue = input("Search for: ")
checkContainer = input("Seach in container named: ")

container = container_switcher.get(checkContainer, None)
if container is None:
    print("Invalid container name: " + checkContainer)
else:
    print(does_it_contain(container, int(checkValue)))
```

Note that you have to convert the `checkValue` to an integer when passing to the `does_it_contain` function, otherwise you will pass it as a string and it will also always return `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `checkContainer` is a string, passing a string to `does_it_contain` function will let it to check whether the value is in the particular `checkContainer` string instead of the container object.

If you want to find the correct container by its name, you could create a dictionary.

```
# Using dictionary

dict = {
    "a": [...],
    "b": {...}
}

def func(name, val):
    print(val in dict[name])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code. You are searching for a string in a set of integers, and that you are just getting a string containing either `setContainer` or `listContainer`, and not the variable values themselves.

To fix the first issue, use `str(i) for i in range(1000)` instead of `i for i in range(1000)`.

For the second issue, change `if value in container:` to `if value in containers[container]:` and to the same for the second `if` statement. Then, change

```py
setContainer = {i for i in range(1000)}
listContainer = [i for i in range(1000)]
```

to

```py
containers = {
  'setContainer': {str(i) for i in range(1000)},
  'listContainer': [str(i) for i in range(1000)]
}
```

so that you can access the values using a string like so: `containers[container]`.

```py
containers = {
  'setContainer': {str(i) for i in range(1000)},
  'listContainer': [str(i) for i in range(1000)]
}


def does_it_contain(container, value):
    if value in containers[container]:
        return True
    if value not in containers[container]:
        return False


checkValue = input("Search for: ")
checkContainer = input("Seach in container named: ")

print(does_it_contain(checkContainer, checkValue))
```

This will throw an error if the container doesn't exist, so you'll have to wrap `print(does_it_contain(checkContainer, checkValue))` in a `try...except` block to check if the user entered an invalid container name.

Answer (score 0):

As also noted in other answers, your code has two issues: looking up a `string` in a list of `int`'s and passing a string with the intent to pass a variable name. Workarounds for both can be found in these answers.

That being said, if you really wanted to *directly* get the variable name using an input field, there are different possibilities for that as well. See [Convert a string to preexisting variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295058/convert-a-string-to-preexisting-variable-names) for details and also for hints on how *not* to do it (i.e. don't use `eval()`!)

One way would be to use the `globals()` function in python that gives you a dictionary of all defined variables:

```
setContainer = {str(i) for i in range(1000)}
listContainer = [str(i) for i in range(1000)]

def does_it_contain(container, value):
    if value in container:
        return True
    if value not in container:
        return False
        
checkValue = input("Search for: ")
checkContainerVarName = input("Seach in container named: ")

print(does_it_contain(globals()[checkContainerVarName], checkValue))
```

will do what you originally intended.