# I have 5 sensors: the sensors read the environment simultaneously

Tags: python

I have 5 sensors:

the sensors read the environment simultaneously

what I am trying to do is increment the sensor number with each scan

```
for i in range(0,5):
self.sensor_i.append(Quantity("HC-SR04.{n}".format(n=i), Quantity.FLOAT))
```

what I am trying to do is,
each iteration I want to increase the sensor number and sensor scaned data
as follow
sensor_1 = sensor data at time 1
sensor_2 = sensor data at time 2
.... etc

How can I increment it without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword `eval`

```
for i in range(0,5):
    eval("self.sensor_" + str(i)).append(Quantity("HC-SR04.{n}".format(n=i), Quantity.FLOAT))
```

Referencing: [Converting string to preexisting variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295058/convert-a-string-to-preexisting-variable-names)